# Массивы в PHP и связке с MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица SUBJ. В ней поля `subj_id`, `subj_credit`, `result`.
Заполнена так:

```
subj_id | subj_credit|result|
1       | 3          |    9 | 
2       | 3          |    8 |
3       | 2          |    8 |
```

Выполнил это:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT subj_id, subj_credit, result from subjects");

$credits = mysql_Fetch_array($result);
```

По книжке понял так, что $credit - это массив. Нужно мне сделать следующее:

```
RATING = (КРЕДИТ1*РЕЗУЛЬТАТ1 + КРЕДИТ2*РЕЗУЛЬТАТ2 + КРЕДИТ-N*РЕЗУЛЬТАТ-N)/СУММАКРЕДИТОВ
```

Тут КРЕДИТ1, КРЕДИТ2, и т.д. - это результаты из **subj_credit**.
РЕЗУЛЬТАТ1, РЕЗУЛЬТАТ2 - значения из **result**.

Подскажите, как сделать это программно. Я примерно понял так:

1. Сперва я посчитаю сколько записей в БД: `$kolvo = count($credits);` считать до тех пор, пока в базе есть записи.
2. А вот дальше в реализации я хз. ((

Куда копать хотя бы.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT subj_id, subj_credit, result from subjects");

$sum1=0;
$kolvo=0;

while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $sum1 += $result_row['subj_credit'] * $result_row['result'];
    $kolvo++;
}

$credit = $sum1/$kolvo;
```

mysql_fetch_array возвращает массив, в котором элементы СТРОКИ каждый раз при вызове, ил ЛОЖЬ, если больше нету.

Comment: Количество так же можно выдернуть функцией mysql_num_rows();

    $kolvo=mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: Всем спасибо:) Ночью поделал и разобралса:)